# Laravel: Passing array from routes to views without mapping it to some keys?

Tags: php, laravel-5

Is it possible?
I can do:

```
Route::get('passit',
    function()
    {
        $data['arr'] = array(1,2,3);
        return View::make('aview', $data);
    });
```

in the view I do:

```
foreach ($arr as $a){
    echo $a;
}
```

The array is mapped with the '*arr*'.

What I want instead is just to :

```
 Route::get('passit',
        function()
        {
            $data = array(1,2,3);
            return View::make('aview', $data);
        });
```

But this doesn't work because `$data` in :

```
foreach ($data as $a){
        echo $a;
    }
```

Is undefined. I also tried :

```
Route::get('passit',
            function()
            {
                $data = array(1,2,3);
                return View::make('aview')->with($data);
            });
```

No luck.

*PHP 5.6, Laravel 5.1*

Note : By the way, I don't bother, not at all just curious if any.

Answer (score 1):

In your route define the variable as.

```
return View::make('aview', compact($data));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 Route::get('passit',
        function()
        {
            $data = array(1,2,3);
            return View::make('aview', ['data' => $data]);
        });
```

Comment: Hmm.. that's the same, using a key as 'data'.

Comment: Yeah, but with this key you can do `foreach ($data as $a){
        echo $a;
    }` Perhaps I don't understand well the question

Comment: I mean it's kinda introducing some coupling, why can't I just do `View::make('aview',  $data);`, but plus_one for answering anyway.